# xml generator script wordpress

Tags: xml

What i want is to have a script that would create an xml output file.

just to give you a brief overview of what i am planning to achieve.

I want me or some user to enter some text in a custom form and when hit GET RESULT an xml file be created with the user inputted infor and some other custom text along with it.

EG.

USER INPUTS : 123456

XML OUTPUT FILE should have 123456

I want this script to run on wordpress online or even on local host is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merry Christmas!

First off, this works but you should never use this in production code - this should only get you pointed in the right direction. Second, the form redirect to itself but you might want to use a [Custom Endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) in WordPress or a simple [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX) call. Before using any info supplied by the user make sure you sanitize everything - Read up on [Data Sanitization and Validation With WordPress](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress--wp-25536).

I also threw in an option to have the file downloaded automatically or display in the browser window. If you want to force the download, make sure the 'Content-disposition' header is set.

Cheers!

```
<?php

// check the method against post action method
// we're looking for POST xml and GET form

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') render_xml();
else if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') render_form();
die();


function render_form(){ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
    <br><br>
    Custom:<br>
    <input type="text" name="custom" value="12345">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GET RESULT">
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="DOWNLOAD">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}

function render_xml(){
  header('Content-type: text/xml');
  if(!empty($_REQUEST['download'])){
    // Force download -- checks the 'name' of the submit button for contents
    $filename = 'the_awesome_file.xml';
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  }
  ?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <firstname><?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?></firstname>
  <lastname><?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?></lastname>
  <custom><?php echo $_POST['custom']; ?></custom>
</root><?php die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help . Can you tell me what if instead of text box i have a textarea where if i enter some text in two rows each row automatically converts into xml file with different tags . eg first row 123 and second row 456 then output would be <ss>123</ss> and <rr>456</rr>

Comment: It's probably best to ask that as another question and post your input and expected output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007412/text-to-xml-conversion-using-php-script?noredirect=1#comment55773796_34007412